# #1932 -Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

windows 7 - xampp

Suddenly my site is not working.Showing this table `db_blog.title_slogan doesn't exist in engine 27` in my index page and my database table show this

> "#1932 -Table 'db_blog.title_slogan' doesn't exist in engine"

Comment: Any chance someone/something has been dropping tables?  Run `SHOW TABLES` from MySQL for your database.

Comment: All tables exist .

Comment: Did you do *any* kind of maintenance or changes to your server?  If you restart the MySQL Server service, what is presented in the error log?

Comment: Which MySQL user is connecting to the DB, and what permissions do they have?