# MySQL phpMyAdmin: Error #1932 - Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb, innodb

in phpMyAdmin I can see all databases and tables. But when clicking on any table I get the error
**Error #1932 - Table 'mytablename' doesn't exist in engine**

I tried a lot of solution advises found on Google and Stackoverflow, but nothing helped for me. Is there a way to extract the data as SQL files that I can import them on a clean installation?

I'm working with XAMPP on Windows 11.

***I have tried dozens of SO threads and the solution advises there. I was not able to find a solution working for me.***

> [Xampp-mysql - "Table doesn't exist in engine" #1932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759870/xampp-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine-1932)
> `- I tried it with new and old files of ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1`
> `- I checked the my.ini for innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend`
>
> [Database corruption with MariaDB : Table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039927/database-corruption-with-mariadb-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- Tried to backup with mysqldump -u root --all-databases > sql_file.sql`
> `Result: mysqldump: Got error: 1932: "Table 'mytablename' doesn't exist in engine" when using LOCK TABLES`
>
> [mysql 1932 table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122742/mysql-1932-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- The old pcs xampp version was 8.1.2, my new one 8.1.4 but i also tried to install the old 8.1.2 version resulting in the same Error.`
>
> [Mysql Table 'db.table' doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70170383/mysql-table-db-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- I'm on Windows, not Ubuntu (Linux)`
>
> [how to fix #1932 - Table does not exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994884/how-to-fix-1932-table-does-not-exist-in-engine)
> `- I already copied the old files which are mentioned, without success.`
>
> [phpMyAdmin error 1932 - table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897427/phpmyadmin-error-1932-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- Running the ALTER command in phpmyadmin also results in Error "#1932 - Table XYZ doesn't exist in engine"`
> `- Changing the $i = 0 to $ = 1 in xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php just brought me php errors.`
>
> [#1932 table 'tablename' doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116426/1932-table-tablename-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- I have no SQL-Backup to feed, otherwise I would have taken this from the beginning.`
>
> [MySql - Error Code: 1932. Table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879514/mysql-error-code-1932-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- I did not add enum field`
>
> [#1932 -Table doesn't exist in engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526754/1932-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine)
> `- No solution advises here`

Comment: the problem is people want a universal recipe while the actual recovery path varies a lot depending on specific scenario. I hope https://youtu.be/014KbCYayuE helps (yes, it's an hour long video. no I cannot write a guide). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a new database in the new MySQL installation, export everything you want from the old installation and import into the new installation.

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you can follow this link on how to **export** data https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214395738-phpMyAdmin-How-to-backup-or-export-a-database-or-table. And this link for **import** https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214395768-phpMyAdmin-How-to-import-a-database-or-table.

Back Story: I had this problem after copying files from an old MySQL install to a different installation of MySQL. I copied a database in `mysql/data/MyDatabaseOld` to the new MySQL installation.
There is a file called **ibdata1** at `mysql/data/ibdata1`, which is the system tablespace. This error occurred because, even though I copied the **MyDatabaseOld** to the new installation, the ibdata1 file in the new installation didn't have this database. So that is why it says "Doesn't exist in engine". Basically, the database doesn't exist in the ibdata1 file. I don't know if there is a way to edit the ibdata1 file. You can try copy the ibdata1 to the new installation, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me in Windows, lost my old course databases after uninstalling old version and installing new one. The people on XAMPP screw this, cause when you uninstall the old version of **xampp**, even though it lets you save the htdocs and **mysql/data** folder, it will remove the **ibdata1** file from there. So after you uninstall, even though you still have all the databases folders in **mysql/data** now that you lost the corresponding ibdata1 file, they are now useless. Copying a new **ibdata1** file from the new installation of **xampp** will not solve this. Basically there is no way to go back. This could have easily been avoided if the **Xampp** uninstaller would not have touch the **mysql/data** folder at all, leaving it to the user to procced, instead of removing few files there and making its content irrelevant after.

Answer (score -2):

1. Run XAMPP as **Administrator**
2. Restore Your Database Backup
3. Change Your MySQL Port **3306** (MariaDB **3307**)

Comment: Running as administrator didn't changed anything. Which Backup you mean? Unfortunatelly i don't have SQL-Backups, just the old mysql/data folder. Changing the Port also didn't change anything. Same error.

Answer (score -2):

[image: 1]

I had this problem after reinstalling Xampp to the latest version.
For my case i replaced my xampp/mysql folder with old mysql folder and it works

Comment: Maybe if you did not uninstall the old xampp version replacing the folder would work like you said. But when you uninstall the old xampp version the mysql/data folder loses the ibdata1 file and its useless.